# how do i get glyphicon in the center of the bootstrap navbar?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

i am trying to get the glyphicon-log-in in the center of the bootstrap navbar and not even getting into the navbar mean it is showing above the navbar, when debugging.

```
<a class="navbar-brand pull-left" href="/"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="Elunika"></a>

<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in" id="logIcon"></span>

<div class="nav-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="#">HOME</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">ABOUT</a>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> WHO, HOW & WHAT? </a>

                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">WHO WE ARE?</a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#">WHAT IS IT?</a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#">HOW IT WORKS?</a>
                    </li>

                </ul>
                    </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">CONTACT US</a>
                </li>
        </ul>
  </div>
```

and css for logIcon is as follows

```
#logIcon{
position: absolute;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}
```

thank you for any help in advance

Comment: Why are you using `position:absolute`? That means it will show at (0,0) = top left corner of the first parent element with position absolute or relative.

Comment: if we go with left:0; and right:0; then it supposed to come in the center.... isn't it...?

Comment: `left:0;` and `right:0;` will make it span the whole width of the containing element

Comment: so what could be the possible way of doing that...?

Comment: i am using position:absolute; so that it won't affect other elements position.

Comment: I don't know really what the result should look like. Can you make a fiddle with the current result and maybe a graphical mockup showing your expected result?

Comment: "http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/navbar-brand-centered" this one is likely to be same as i want, difference is i want glyphicon in the center instead of brand

Comment: then you only need to replace the text "brand" with your glyphicon span. I tried it, it works

Comment: can you put that as an answer here...?

Comment: because in that glyphicon is not visible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your linked bootsnipp, you only have to replace the word "brand" with your glyphicon span.

```
<div class="navbar-brand navbar-brand-centered"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in" id="logIcon"></span></div>
```

Here's the code in a working fiddle: http://www.bootply.com/EmzUMHPXqd

Answer (score 1):

http://www.bootply.com/eHiWDODA83

You could create a new class for the icon like this..

```
.navbar-center
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

And then use markup like this..

```
<nav class="navbar" role="navigation">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>    
  </div>
  <a class="navbar-center navbar-text" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in" id="logIcon"></span></a>
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="Elunika"></a>

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li class="active">
        <a href="#">HOME</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">ABOUT</a>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> WHO, HOW &amp; WHAT? </a>

        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li>
            <a href="#">WHO WE ARE?</a>
          </li>

          <li>
            <a href="#">WHAT IS IT?</a>
          </li>

          <li>
            <a href="#">HOW IT WORKS?</a>
          </li>

        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">CONTACT US</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

http://www.bootply.com/eHiWDODA83

Comment: I'm using it without the "absolute" attribute and it works nicely.